# Web debug toolbar for Phalcon?

Tags: php, debugging, plugins, phalcon

Is there any **web debug toolbar** in Phalcon that shows time and memory consumption with each request?

Something like this **[Redesigned Web Debug Toolbar](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-redesigned-web-debug-toolbar)** from Symfony framework?

Comment: There is http://phpdebugbar.com/ . Anyway, on this site, asking for (recommended) resources/libraries is not on-topic as it doesn't have a clear and correct answer (there can be 1000 correct answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at phalcon-debugbar, which is cloned from laravel.
this tool maybe could help you.
https://packagist.org/packages/snowair/phalcon-debugbar